# How to add an event handler to a static class event of a generic type T?

Tags: c#, generics, events, static

This one's a bit esoteric.

Consider the following code:

```c#
class MyObject {
  public static event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}

class Container<T> {
  public Container() {
    T.SomeEvent += OnSomeEvent;   // will not compile
  }
  void OnSomeEvent(object sender, object eventArgs) { }
}

Container<MyObject> foo;
```

Of course this will not compile, because the compiler doesn't know the type of `T` at compile time. More specifically, it doesn't know for certain that it has the event in question.

How do I attach an event handler to a *static* event `SomeEvent` of template parameter `T`? Do I need to do messy reflection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to use reflection here - and it will be messy. I would also suggest using `Type` instead of `<T>` here, as `static class` etc can't be used with `<T>`, which could limit the usage. However, as a general rule: you should actively minimize static events *anyway* (they're a great way to cause memory leaks, and are hard to isolate), so it *might* be preferable to use an alternative design altogether.

Comment: What do you mean by "using `Type` instead of `<T>` here"?

Comment: @SodAlmighty having a method that takes a `Type` as a parameter.